# grep in JQuery to C#

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I have a snippet of code that I wrote in Javascript/jQuery to search through a list of items. Does grep exist in C#, or is there a better way to do it?

```
var items;
var itemCount = 0; 

var result = $.grep(items, function (v, i) {
            //change title and description to lowercase to match search
            lowerCaseTitle = v.title.toLowerCase();
            lowerCaseDesc = v.description.toLowerCase();
            if (lowerCaseTitle.indexOf(lowerCaseSearch) > -1 || lowerCaseDesc.indexOf(lowerCaseSearch) > -1) {
                var newLI = createLI(i, v.title);
                $('#searchResults').append(newLI);
                itemCount++;
            }
            return v;
        });
```

I think I just want to search through a JSON string that I created using the JSONTextWriter. It puts in the id, title, and description of each item. If the title or description (or subset of title/description) matches the search term passed through, add it to another list.

Comment: That's not vanilla javascript, it's a jquery function.  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/  In addition, you could compare the two function's source code to find out if it works in the same manner.

Comment: C# has a grep function? Where?

Comment: I would use LINQ Js, have used it in some projects and works really great, specially if you are familiar with it from C#: [link](https://linqjs.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `grep` method in C# but there is LINQ `Where` method which is used for the same purposes. I think for parsing JSON the best option will be to use [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json). So your code might look like that:

```
var json = "YOUR JSON ARRAY";
var searchTerm = "SEARCH TERM";

var jarray = JArray.Parse(json);
var searchResults = jarray
    .Where(x =>
        x["title"].Value<string>().ToLower().Contains(searchTerm) ||
        x["description"].Value<string>().ToLower().Contains(searchTerm))
    .ToList();
```

You can read more about using LINQ with JSON.Net [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm).

The proposed solution is using `ToLower` and `Contains` methods. Both of them are specific to current culture. If you don't want to be dependent on current culture settings, you can use this method:

```
x => x["title"].Value<string>().IndexOf(searchTerm, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0
```

Comment: This is perfect. I'll totally pass in the json and searchTerm and then use JArray. Thanks!!